# what are the parameters for elevated button widget

Tags: flutter

Please I'm getting errors under the parameters I used for my '`ElevatedButton`'
....Need help please

```
child: ElevatedButton(
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: mainColor,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html

You can use properties like this,

```
ElevatedButton(
     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(elevation: 5.0, 
            primary: mainColor, 
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
          onPressed: () {  },
          child:Container()),
```

Comment: but primary gets underlined and canceled

Comment: Means? What is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

`ElevatedButton` required parameter are `onPressed` and `child` and you can use `ElevatedButton` as:

```
 ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Elevated Button'),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  primary: Colors.red,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

As of flutter version 3.3.2 elevated button has following properties/params

```
Key? key,   
required void Function()? onPressed,   
void Function()? onLongPress,   
void Function(bool)? onHover,   
void Function(bool)? onFocusChange,   
ButtonStyle? style,  
FocusNode? focusNode,   
bool autofocus = false,   
Clip clipBehavior = Clip.none,   
MaterialStatesController? statesController,   
required Widget? child,
```

You can use ElevatedButton.styleFrom function to define elevated button style as

```
ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            elevation: elevation,
            backgroundColor: bgColor ?? colorScheme.primary,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius ?? 30),
            )
            //elevation: 8,
            ),
```